# Detect bootstrap modal to change destination of keypress input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code to detect the keypress and direct input towards my searchbar with id="search".

```
    $( document ).keypress(function() {
  $("#search").focus();
```

I also have a bootstrap modal dialog with input fields. Is there a way to detect if the modal is open or not--if it is open, direct the input to the first field of the modal?

```
<div class="modal fade" id="signup" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <input id="input_modal" placeholder="" size="14" autofocus="autofocus"><br>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="hide"/>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For Bootstrap 3:

```
if ($("element").data('modal') && $("element").data('modal').isShown) {
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $("#search").focus();
})
```